# What is the doctor saying in this sentence? Neither subtitles nor my ear can get it correct :(

Tags: grammar, listening

This is from a British TV show, a patient who fell off the bike and hurt her leg is at the doctor's office. [Hospital visit](https://youtu.be/zq6CDfVY-Ck?list=PLTgR-LHLS9mZskKPMpklzJlCBV4NAxIQR&t=409s) (6:49-6:55)

The doctor says something looking at her arm, but neither the subtitles nor what I heard makes sense.

1- Is it the rest that saw where it is swollen? (This is the subtitles and I know it is not correct.)

I have listened to it many times, however, what I hear doesn't make sense, either. It sounds like I hear two different versions, but none doesn't make sense. Here is what it sounds like to me:

1- **Is it the rested sore** where it is swollen?

2- **Is it the rest at sore** where it is swollen?

What is it that I miss? What is the doctor really saying?

Comment: Wrist is pronounced /rɪst/, and rest is pronounced /rɛst/.  You need to listen for the difference between the short "i" and the "e" vowels to differentiate these words.

Comment: Also note that in Br.Eng, we don't actually say "at the doctor's office". This seems to be used in Am.Eng.  Usually in Br.Eng we say "at the doctor's surgery", or "GP surgery", often shortened to simply "at the doctors", or "at the GP".  "Surgery" here means the place you go for advice/a consultation, not for actual surgical treatment.

Comment: @BillyKerr, thanks, that was very informative.

Comment: My wife sang that song when she was a little girl. In the US version, the rhyme was "... pill, pill, pill and I'll be back in the morning with my bill, bill, bill".

Comment: You can add `&t=409` to the end of your URL for the video to make it start at 6:49.

Comment: @shoover, thanks, I didn't know that. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Yunus or &t=6m49s

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Subtitles are wrong and have confused you.  She says "wrist" not "rest".

> Is it the wrist that's sore, where it's swollen?
>
> Yes, it is.

"where it's swollen" is acting as a relative phrase, not a question.  "Is it the wrist, where it's swollen, that is sore?

Comment: The subtitles look like they are done by speech recognition software, because they call the character "face" instead of "Fizz" at one point.

Comment: @DJClayworth a lot of youtube subtitles are. I feel genuinely sorry for people with hearing impairments on ~50% of videos. Likewise, there are some channels where I can only imagine that the creators (or their teams, probably) have actually gone through to meticulously subtitle it correctly. With the automatic closed captions being so bad, it's relatively clear which producers make the effort

Comment: Subtitles can be strange.  In Arabic subtitles are usually in classical Arabic so have no relation to what the people are saying apart from the overall meaning.